# Recycle previous canvas when drawing in Quartz 2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, canvas, quartz-2d

I'd like to be able to draw on top of the existing canvas when redrawing a view. How is this possible?

This is the way I am drawing at the moment:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // save the current state, as we'll overwrite this
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    /*
     draw a line across the top of the view
     */
    // move the pen to the starting point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 10);
    // draw a line to another point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 190, 60);

    /*
     draw a rectangle just below, with a stroke on the outside.
     */
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(60, 100, 180, 90));

    /*
     write the previous to the context then
     change the colour to blue and the stroke to 2px.
     */
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);

    /*
     draw a circle filling most of the rest of the box.
     */
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));

    // do the actual drawing
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    // restore the state back after drawing on it.
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
```

---

**Wanted solution** pseudocode / behaviour:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
      Retrieve previously drawn canvas 
       If available then 
            Create new drawings 
            Draw them on top of previous canvas
       If not then
            Create drawings
            Draw them on canvas
            Save canvas so that is available for the next drawRect call
}
```

Comment: Does not calling CGContextRestoreGState at the end work?

Comment: No it doesn't as the path information is not saved in the "context". I am experimenting with retaining a reference to a CGMutablePathRef but haven't had much success on it..